# Calculating the commutator of exponentials

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Suppose that $A,B,C$ are $n\times n$ matrices related by $[A,B] = C$. Is there a closed expression for the commutator of the exponentials $[\text{Exp}(A),\text{Exp}(B)]$ ?

Comment: I am afraid you need to use the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) formula.

Comment: I suppose you mean $\exp (A+B) = \exp(A)\exp(B) = \exp(B)\exp(A)$ @DietrichBurde. Thanks for both comments.

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52012/3255) there is a formula for $[A, e^B]$. (On Physics.SE).

Comment: And the above formula can be utilized twice to produce a double integral expression linear in $[A,B]$.